# Show json array list in drop down angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, ng-options

I am new in AngularJS and trying to show data in drop down list and facing few errors. 
Here is my **JSON** data:

```
$scope.list=[
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Groups": [
        "xyz",
        "abc",
        "ugh",
        "ccd"
    ]
}
]
```

I am trying to show list of names of Groups mentioned in the json.

**In controller :-**

```
$scope.selectedval = $scope.list[0].Groups;
console.log($scope.selectedval);
```

In **View** I am doing this :-

```
ng-options="item.Groups for item in list"
```

By doing this I am getting all the datas in single option. How to separate datas on each list by ng-option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-options="item for item in list[0].Groups"

Comment: Sorry, it is list[0], I renamed it. Try it.
I sent you sample code too. Please click the below URL
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRC5CNQZOGMS

Answer (score 1):

In view try this

```
ng-options="val for val in selectedval"
```

Comment: Worked Thanks. Showing in the list , but when selecting it , breaking down to character .

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.list:[{"$id": "1",
"Groups": [
    "xyz",
    "abc",
    "ugh",
    "ccd"
]}]
$scope.list=[] // replace ":" by "="
```

Comment: Ok sorry my mistake it's actually `=` only . I am editing the question . Still not coming.